# How do I update a model after click in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a bunch of 'campaigns' in my database:

```
{"name" : "Apple", "status" : "active"}
{"name" : "Orange", "status" : "paused"}
```

I've displayed them in Angular with:

```
<span ng-switch on="campaign.status"> 
<a ng-switch-when="active" ng-click='setStatus($index, "paused")'>Pause</a>
<a ng-switch-when="paused" ng-click='setStatus($index,"active")'>Activate</a>
</span>
```

Then in my controller I update the status on the server's database using an API (which returns JSON of the updated entry.

```
$scope.setStatus = function(index, newstatus) {

    var item = $scope.campaigns[index];
    var url = 'api.mysite.com/' + newstatus + '/' + item._id.$oid;

    if (! $scope.isComplete(item) )
    {
        $http({method: 'GET', url: url}).  
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) { 
           $scope.campaigns[index] = data; 
          }). error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
           console.log('Error communicating with the server.');
          }); 
    }
}
```

Where the variable `campaigns` is an array of all the campaigns retrieved from the server when the controller is initialized with:

```
$scope.connection = $resource('api.mysite/getallcampaigns');
$scope.campaigns = $scope.connection.query();
```

This seems really messy already and I'm pretty sure I'm using AngularJS incorrectly :( The main thing is that I'm passing into the controller the index of the element I'm modifying, which break if I re-order the array. How can I get Angular to wire this up nicely for me? What's the minimal and correct way to do this?

Comment: You can use indexOf. Check this example. http://jsfiddle.net/KNM4q/113/

Answer (score 0):

Pass campaign into setStatus() instead of an index.  Modify the campaign properties in the success callback:

```
<a ng-switch-when="active" ng-click='setStatus(campaign, "paused")'>Pause</a>
```

.

```
$scope.setStatus = function (campaign, newstatus) {
   ...
   success(function(data, status, headers, config) { 
       campaign.status = data.status;
```

Don't reassign the entire array in the success callback -- that will likely break databinding in your view.
  I.e., I don't think this will work: `campaign = data`

You can probably define one $resource object that can handle both getting the initial array of data and modifying individual array items.  See the "Credit card resource" example on the [$resource API page](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource).  Note how each item of array `cards` (which is assigned the result of query()) can also be $save()d.